# I want to master ASP.NET - What concepts should I focus on/What concepts do you most value?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I start a job this summer doing work in ASP.NET 4 (C#). I plan on working with some legacy code as well as MVC.

I want to get a running start. I have good understanding of HTML/CSS/Javascript, and pretty good understanding of C# itself, Design principles, Design Patterns, and understand masterpages, basic MVC2, and code behinds for web forms.

- In your opinion what aspects of
  ASP.NET are the most important to
  master for web applications?
- What do
  you value most in your usage of
  ASP.NET?
- Do you have a recommendation
  for understanding the internals of
  ASP.NET itself?

Comment: First things first, take any information about practices or standards that come from the domain *.microsoft.com, and ignore those, also delete any bookmarks or favorites you have to them as well.

Answer (score 13):

#### ASP.NET Webforms

A proper understanding of the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), [the request pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx) and [state management (cookies, sessions, viewstate, ...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) will be a great benefit.

#### ASP.NET MVC

Make sure you understand how HTTP works (difference between POST and GET), how routing, controllers and views work together and how you can influence them.

Comment: +1 for page lifecycle. This is something very important that is often overlooked when learning ASP.Net.

Comment: i would also add - cookies/sessions/viewstate and the advantages/disadvantages of using them

Comment: @k25 - cookies, sessions and viewstate are included in "state management". The advantages and disadvantages of using them are of course part of understanding them :-)

Comment: +1 for page life cycle. This bit trips up most ASP.NET devs out there.

Comment: @Kristof Claes - Yes you are right. But beginners (at times) do not pay attention to such details. Myself included when I started. Initially I was using Sessions a lot and then reduced the usage if unnecessary. So I thought an emphasis is required ;)

Comment: @k25 - You're absolutely right; these things can't be emphasized enough.

Answer (score 4):

Webforms: Understanding the page life-cycle and post-back mechanism, ViewState and Session State. Know the standard controls.

MVC: Understand how HTTP works (GET, POST requests, for example). Understand separation of concerns. Dependency Injection. Know your HTML, JavaScript by hand. jQuery.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what he listed he knows?

Comment: Yes there is overlap. However, he asked for my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

What I would suggest you look deeper into:

- jQuery and jQuery UI
- AJAX and Web Methods
- Repeaters
- Dynamically created controls. In particular, their lifecycle, viewstate quarks, and how events are processed.

I've noticed that in a lot of legacy code, controls are created and added to the page via the code behind more than they should be.

Comment: Repeaters make you learn just about everything.

Comment: @Jeff O - I love repeaters. I tell all new web devs under me to read up on them. The make life so much easier.

Comment: Can you recommend any good sources. ASP.NET has a few tutorials. A google search was pretty frustrating.

Comment: @Jeff O - I like this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx And for nested repeaters: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetNestedRepeaters.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tyanna. I guess if you can nest repeaters you can do about anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're way ahead of the game already. Really though, nothings going to prepare you for digging into other people's code (which you'll be doing a lot, especially in the enterprise world). By that I mean, work on your soft skills. I've found those to be just as, if not more, valuable than my programming skills.